# Conservation of Strangeness

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, standard-model, quarks, weak-interaction

[image]

The above image is considered to be a reaction that can occur practically. However, isn't the strangeness of $\Xi^-$ -2, and $\Lambda^0$ -1? This would leave a net -1 value on the left side of the equation. So am I right? Or is this a conceptual error?

Comment: So it is a weak interaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strangeness is not necessarily conserved in decays mediated by the weak force. In this case one of the strange quarks decays to $u$, $\bar u$ and $d$ via a weak interaction so strangeness is not conserved.

[image: Xi- decay]

(picture from [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/xi.html))

The relatively long lifetime of $1.64 \times 10^{-10}$ seconds is characteristic of a weak interaction.

Comment: May I suggest adding [this image](http://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2002/feynman/exampl10.gif) for clarity?

Comment: So if it's decaying via weak interaction, I can just ignore the strangeness?How can I tell if a decay is governed by a weak interaction or a strong interaction?

Comment: @AntaraKulkarni: if a flavour change occurs it has to be a weak decay as both the EM and strong interactions conserve flavour.